# Google Play app hangs during updates

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates

I have Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman with android 2.3.4. Recently, every time I try to update my apps over WiFi, the updates get stuck and I have to cancel that particular update to proceed. Now, however, every app I try to update gets stuck. I ensure that no other download is running in the background but no effect.

I have about 45MB free out of 320MB.

What might be the reason for this? How to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have enough space to store the downloads? Perhaps enclosing a log capture would help diagnose the problem. Could try updating one by one individually instead of doing it all in the one go?

Comment: @t0mm13b I have enough space for updates, 40MB for a ~15MB app. Single update has better results but its too hectic. Its a nightmare. Any ideas?